# PostgreSQL Partitioning - Constraint exclusion not working

Tags: partitioning, constraint, postgresql-9.6

I have a table with about 9 million rows where i'm keeping customer's id, a timestamp, and a cost value for the particular date-time.

It looks like this:

```
customer|t|consumption
```

I need to split my dataset into smaller tables which will inherit from the table master.

Master table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_master (
 customer TEXT NOT NULL,
 t TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 consumption INTEGER NOT NULL 
);
```

Child tables:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_2 (
CHECK ( t='2013-07-01 01:00:00')
) INHERITS (my_table_master);

CREATE TABLE my_table_3 (
CHECK ( my_extract(t)=0 )
) INHERITS (my_table_master);

CREATE TABLE my_table_4 (
CHECK ( t <> '2013-07-01 01:00:00' AND my_extract(t) <> 0 )
) INHERITS (my_table_master);
```

**The problem**

Constraint exclusion is not working here. Note that i have already execute the command:

```
SET constraint_exclusion = on;
```

If for example i run the following query, the planner includes my_table_2 and my_table_3 instead of just `my_table_2`.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table_master WHERE t='2013-07-01 01:00:00';
```

Query Plan:

```
Append  (cost=0.00..24601.55 rows=967 width=24) (actual time=164.514..164.693 rows=993 loops=1)
->  Seq Scan on public.my_table_master  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=44) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=0 loops=1)
 Output: my_table_master.customer, my_table_master.t, my_table_master.consumption
 Filter: (my_table_master.t = '2013-07-01 01:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
 ->  Seq Scan on public.my_table_3  (cost=0.00..24577.43 rows=960 width=24) (actual time=164.472..164.472 rows=0 loops=1)
 Output: my_table_3.customer, my_table_3.t, my_table_3.consumption
 Filter: (my_table_3.t = '2013-07-01 01:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
 Rows Removed by Filter: 1237954
 ->  Seq Scan on public.my_table_2  (cost=0.00..24.13 rows=6 width=44) (actual time=0.029..0.165 rows=993 loops=1)
 Output: my_table_2.customer, my_table_2.t, my_table_2.consumption
 Filter: (my_table_2.t = '2013-07-01 01:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
 Planning time: 0.298 ms
 Execution time: 164.731 ms
```

**EDIT:**

If i'm only asking two specific queries on the DB that include the following WHERE clauses respectively:

```
WHERE t='2013-07-01 01:00:00' 
WHERE my_extract(t)=0
```

do you think i should possibly split my dataset in a different way? 
If yes, please let me know.

Comment: It is based on the PostgreSQL documentation about partitioning.
"With constraint exclusion enabled, the planner will examine the constraints of each partition and try to prove that the partition need not be scanned because it could not contain any rows meeting the query's WHERE clause. When the planner can prove this, it excludes the partition from the query plan."

Comment: [Cross posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328) from http://stackoverflow.com/q/41654542/330315

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This partitioning schema is designed to improve specific queries performance by placing most of the heavily accessed rows of the table in a single partition. I'm afraid the problems originate from my constraints, maybe they need some change.

Comment: I take out my comment about exlusion constraints vs. constraint exclusions. My misreading.

Comment: *my_table_master* (as it doesn't have any constraint) will always be included. my_table_2 *should be* included, because the constraint does not relate in any way to the WHERE in your query. I agree with you that it should *not* need to scan my_table_4. Have you tried something subtle, such as explicitly casting the timestamps with `::timestamp with no time zone`? It might just be that they're not interpreted in the same way (i.e.: TIME ZONE)

Comment: @joanolo Do you mean my_table_3 ?
Also, it does include only the first two tables (my_table_  2  & 3), not 4 .
Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: So what's he problem? Why should table_3 be excluded for rows that have `WHERE t='2013-07-01 01:00:00'`? Why should it be only table_2?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ One problem was that my_table_3 was being involved (i think we 're fine with that now). An other question is if an other partitioning schema would be better considering my queries. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On closer inspection... PostgreSQL is actually functioning *as expected*:

1. `my_table_master` **is** scanned because there is no constraint on it. The master table can actually have rows, there's nothing preventing it in PostgreSQL inheritance.
2. `my_table_3` **is** scanned because its check constraint (`t='2013-07-01 01:00:00'`) doesn't have anything to do (in principle) with the condition in the `WHERE` clause. Even if the definition of the function `my_extract` makes `my_extract(t) = 0` incompatible with `t='2013-07-01 01:00:00'`, the database is clearly not *"intelligent enough"* to infer it. You could add, if appropriate, even if redundant, `NOT (my_extract(t) = 0)` in your where clause. That would prevent `my_table_3` from being scanned.
3. `my_table_2` **is** scanned as expected.
4. `my_table_4` **is not** actually scanned.

So, the constraints prevent **one** table from being scanned out of the 4.

Alternate query, adding the (my_extract(t) = 0) clause:

```
EXPLAIN 
    SELECT * 
    FROM my_table_master 
    WHERE t='2013-07-01 01:00:00' 
          AND NOT (my_extract(t) = 0)  /* This is the new addition */ ;
```

returns

```
Append  (cost=0.00..309.45 rows=7 width=44)
  ->  Seq Scan on my_table_master  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=44)
        Filter: ((t = '2013-07-01 01:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (my_extract(t) <> 0))
  ->  Seq Scan on my_table_2  (cost=0.00..309.45 rows=6 width=44)
        Filter: ((t = '2013-07-01 01:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (my_extract(t) <> 0))
```

### By adding the extra condition, the scan of `my_table_3` is prevented.

NOTE: To make the trials, I've made up `my_extract` like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_extract(_t timestamp without time zone) 
RETURNS integer AS
$$
begin
    return extract(day from _t)::integer ;
end
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE /* attention! */ ;
```

I've used plpgsql to ensure it is not inlined (even if it could be trivially done). Notice that it is necessary that the function be labeled as **`IMMUTABLE`** (that is, its result only depends on its parameters), or it won't work as expected.

### ADDENDUM

```
EXPLAIN 
    SELECT * FROM my_table_master 
    WHERE my_extract(t) = 0 ;

  Append  (cost=0.00..613.25 rows=13 width=44)
    ->  Seq Scan on my_table_master  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=44)
          Filter: (my_extract(t) = 0)
    ->  Seq Scan on my_table_2  (cost=0.00..306.62 rows=6 width=44)
          Filter: (my_extract(t) = 0)
    ->  Seq Scan on my_table_3  (cost=0.00..306.62 rows=6 width=44)
          Filter: (my_extract(t) = 0)
```

Works as well as expected:

1. `my_table_master` -> as before
2. `my_table_2` -> is scanned because its constraint doesn't have any immediate relation to
3. `my_table_3` -> is scanned because its constraint actually *match* the WHERE clause.

What PostgreSQL could do (and it doesn't) is eliminate the `FILTER my_extract(t)=0` when scanning table 3, because the condition is already known to be true. Let's hope this optimization is implemented at some point in the future.

Comment: Thanks for this nice explanation!
I was also wondering if it eliminates or not the Filter: my_extract(t)=0, you covered that too.

Can you consider of a better alternative partitioning schema having in mind my most asked queries? For example, could i possibly split my dataset by day or month and then be able to ask those two queries ?

Comment: When you work with temporal data such as *logs* or *(lots of) sensor readings*, it is quite normal to use some partitioning by *date period* (be it a `day`, an `isoweek` or a `month`). You don't always do it because of optimization (it does help if there are lots of queries with a where clause containing a time range, and some condition that actually requires a table scan). You tend to optimize your queries by using **indices** (perhaps **partial** indices, or **functional** indices, and **multi-column** indices, and [less frequently] with GIN or GIST indices).

Comment: A common use for partitioning is ease of maintenance (you don't need to backup tables you know want change any more, for instance; or you can drop the oldest tables when the age of data makes it irrelevant). With 9 M rows, I would be quite comfortable *not* partitioning at all.